# Creating Jpegs Server Side with Winforms App and c#

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing

I have a winforms app that loads some images and text and saves the compilation as a jpeg.
This all works on my pc, but I need this to run on my web server.  When I run it on the server while logged in to remote desktop, it works great, if I run it while not connected, it creates solid black images.  In my winforms app, I am loading my content into a panel and then using the drawtoImage function of the panel to export the image.
Any ideas on how I could get this to work server side?

Comment: Your title suggests it's a winforms app, but your question leads one to believe that it's a webforms app. Very confusing. Please revise this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the method of creating the control in memory and then using drawtobitmap works great for me, thanks for your input

Answer (score 1):

OK ,how i understood this is a Desktop Application .
If so than you should keep the Session as Logged In ,which will cause trouble ,if you want to log in from another Machine it wont allow you ,or you can use Team Viewer for Remote Access and leave Administrator Account on you're Web Server as Logged In ,i think that will solve you're problem .

Comment: I am still testing now, and am starting to see some success if I load the panel in memory instead of on the screen and use drawtobitmap on that.  Ill post my progress.  Thanks for the ideas though.

Comment: But even if you load the Panel in Memory ,i think when Control is Hidden than DrawToBitmap() Method will lose it's Functionality ,and the Way that Method works i think it Takes The Point where Control is Displayed on Screen than it Capture's the screen in that Possition.

Comment: OK, the method of creating the control in memory and then using drawtobitmap works great for me, thanks for your input.